# Trouble Accessing Dynamically Added Nodes To XML Object

Tags: javascript

I have a XML object ***xmlObj*** (returned in ajax response) in JavaScript as below -

```
<books>
    <book title="Dork Diaries" author="Rachel Renee Russell"></book>
    <book title="Dragon in the Tunnel" author="Ruskin Bond"></book>
    <book title="The Fox" author="Frederick Forsyth"></book>
</books>
```

I am trying to dynamically add a node like this -

```
var _tempNode = document.createElement("book");
_tempNode.setAttribute("title", "Captive");
_tempNode.setAttribute("author", "Tony Park");
xmlObj.appendChild(_tempNode);
```

When I inspect element in Chrome I can see the updated xmlObj as -

```
<books>
    <book title="Dork Diaries" author="Rachel Renee Russell"></book>
    <book title="Dragon in the Tunnel" author="Ruskin Bond"></book>
    <book title="The Fox" author="Frederick Forsyth"></book>
    <book title="Captive" author="Tony Park"></book>
</books>
```

But when I try to select the newly added node it returns NULL

```
xmlObj.querySelector('book[title="Captive"]')) // NULL
```

However, this returns valid node -

```
xmlObj.querySelector('book[title="Dork Diaries"]')) // <book title="Dork Diaries" author="Rachel Renee Russell"></book>
```

Any idea how can I access newly added nodes?

Comment: Your code works for me as expected.

Comment: You can probably try with `xmlObj.children[2]` and `xmlObj.children[3]` to make sure.

Comment: @dereli right am able to access it using children. Not sure why querySelector is failing in my case. Thank you for your time!